# Will this be still otsu Binarization?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have binarized an image using `graythresh`, I want to know by using `graythresh`,  dividing and multiplying the original values by maximum values, is this binarization method still  Otsu , if not what name can we use for this.

```
 im = imread('flower.jpg');
 max_level = double(max(im(:))); 
 min_level = double(min(im(:)));
 lev = graythresh(double(im)/max_level) * max_level;
 bw = (im>=lev);
```

Comment: Yes it is, you are just scaling the image!

Comment: scaled Otsu Binarization? Or Normalized?

Comment: @GameOfThrows not even. Its literally the same thing. Otsu works with histograms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof that you are doing EXACTLY Otsu:

```
 im = (imread('coins.png'));
 max_level = double(max(im(:))); 
 min_level = double(min(im(:)));
 lev1 = graythresh(double(im)/max_level) * max_level;



 %// if instead of offseting and scalling we just put the image
 lev2=graythresh(im);
 % // and as graythresh returns the value between 0-1 we scale it between 0-255
 lev2=lev2*255;
```

Both levels are 126. You are not using any variation of Otsu, but Otsu itself.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Comment: my image is 12 bit(Dicom) with 4096 gray shades.

Comment: @ShoaibAfridi Doesn't matter the type of the image. If This post helped you, consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri i have accepted it because it helped me.

Comment: @ShoaibAfridi thanks I appreciate it. For the future, knwo that this is the standard way of working in Stackoverflow. When someone answers your questions sucesfully it is great for everyone if you accept the answer ;) Thanks